# Can't Get an XML like string to parse in Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I have a string like this:

```
<note><url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These are the Notes of Page 1</notes></note>
<note><url>urlofpage2</url><notes>These are the Notes of Page 2</notes></note>
```

I've been trying to parse it so I can get the notes based on the URL:

so

notesofpage1 = getNotes('urlofpage1')

Here's one thing I tried but it doesn't work for some reason.

```
var xml = '<note><url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These notes should load!</notes></note><note><url>urlofpage2</url><notes>These are the Notes of Page 2</notes></note>';
var $xml = $(xml);

var $notes = $xml.find('url')
                 .filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'urlofpage1' })
                 .closest('notes');
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function getNotes(urltext) {
    var notes;
    var xmlString = "<note><url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These notes should load!</notes></note><note><url>urlofpage2</url><notes>These are the Notes of Page 2</notes></note>";

    $(xmlString).find('url').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == urltext) {
        notes = $(this).next("notes").text();
        }
    });

   return notes;
}

var notesofpage1 = getNotes('urlofpage1');
var notesofpage2 = getNotes('urlofpage2');

alert("page 1: " + notesofpage1 + " page 2: " + notesofpage2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kqMhk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire xml string in a root element and call $.parseXML();

```
var xmlString  = '<root><note><url>urlofpage1</url><notes>These notes should load!</notes></note><note><url>urlofpage2</url><notes>These are the Notes of Page 2</notes></note></root>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlString);
```

Comment: Is that ) after root a typo? Where do I go from there? Sorry i'm really new to XML parsing, I don't know what the parseXML function even accomplishes, I looked at the JQuery docs and it doesn't have many good examples..

Comment: I did have a typo in the parseXML() function, the variable name I was passing in was incorrect.  Heres a good read on XML and jQuery: http://www.compoc.com/tuts/.

Comment: I've created a fiddle with some code for you to look at.  Make sure you have a browser with a console or firebug to view it. http://jsfiddle.net/bittersweetryan/Ff8DA/

Comment: Ok that kind of makes sense, How would I print out only the notes of only the one that contains 'urlofpage1' for example?